# General input/output error when trying to open .rtf files with LibreOffice

Tags: rtf, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am getting "General input/output error" when trying to open some of the RTF files with LibreOffice Writer. I've tried both versions LibreOffice 7.5.5 and 7.6.0

If I open them with Wordpad or Word and Save As RTF files again, then i am able to open them with LibreOffice with no issue.  I've been trying to figure out if there's an issue with some of the files that won't open with LibreOffice but no luck so far. If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open the file as text, say with Notepad++. Maybe special characters or such. You could compare a repaired version with the original.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and please read "[ask]". -- As Joop suggested, compare the original and the repaired files with any file comparison tool. RTF is similar to HTML a text based document format and can easily be read by humans. You might want to [edit] your question and add your findings. -- While your [edit]ing, please add an answerable question. For your apparent issue you have found a solution. So what do you want us to answer?

Comment: Comparing the repaired version with the original is almost impossible due to the code that gets changed or added to the file. It is way too much code in the repaired version which makes it difficult comparing them.

Comment: If the files are too large to easily compare, then narrow down the problem by saving only a small part where the issue occurs. After that, it shouldn't be too hard to use a diff tool to see the changes.

Comment: Even a small part of a repaired file contains too much code and it is different. However, i did compare a correct file and a “wrong” one (without opening and saving them using Word or Wordpad) and found out that a space was needed after \v. I added that space programmatically on all my files and now they open just fine.